# how to make sidebar and the content inside it fit the whole webpages

Tags: html, css

so i was trying to figure out on how to make the sidebar and the content inside fit the whole thing and it not being looking like its in a 4:3 resolution
how it looks like currently

[image]

ive tried changing the styles.css and it resulted it looking the same. i was expecting it to fit the whole webpages and not make it looks like its stuck in a 4:3 resolution
index file

```
<?php
include "header.php";
include "sidebar.php";
?>
<div class="card mt-2">
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        Data Barang
                        <?php
                        include '../koneksi.php';
                        $data_produk = mysqli_query($koneksi,"SELECT * FROM produk");
                        $jumlah_produk = mysqli_num_rows($data_produk);
                        ?>
                        <h3><?php echo $jumlah_produk; ?></h3>
                        <a href="data_barang.php" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">Detail</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        Data Pembelian
                        <?php
                        include '../koneksi.php';
                        $data_penjualan = mysqli_query($koneksi,"SELECT * FROM penjualan");
                        $jumlah_penjualan = mysqli_num_rows($data_penjualan);
                        ?>
                        <h3><?php echo $jumlah_penjualan; ?></h3>
                        <a href="pembelian.php" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">Detail</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        Data Pengguna
                        <?php
                        include '../koneksi.php';
                        $data_petugas = mysqli_query($koneksi,"SELECT * FROM petugas");
                        $jumlah_petugas = mysqli_num_rows($data_petugas);
                        ?>
                        <h3><?php echo $jumlah_petugas; ?></h3>
                        <a href="data_pengguna.php" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">Detail</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
include "footer.php";
?>
```

sidebar file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="author" content="" />
        <title>UKK KASIR</title>
        <!-- Favicon-->
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/favicon.ico" />
        <!-- Core theme CSS (includes Bootstrap)-->
        <link href="../css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="d-flex" id="wrapper">
            <!-- Sidebar-->
            <div class="border-end bg-white" id="sidebar-wrapper">
                <div class="sidebar-heading border-bottom bg-light"><b>KASIR</b></div>
                <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
                    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item-light p-3" href="index.php">Beranda</a>
                    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item-light p-3" href="data_barang.php">Data Barang</a>
                    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item-light p-3" href="pembelian.php">Pembelian</a>
                    <!--<a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item-light p-3" href="stok_barang.php">Stok Barang</a>-->
                    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item-light p-3" href="data_pengguna.php">Data Pengguna</a>
                    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item-light p-3" href="../index.php">Keluar</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Page content wrapper-->
            <div id="page-content-wrapper">
                <!-- Top navigation-->
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light border-bottom">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <button class="btn" id="sidebarToggle"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
                        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
                    </div>
                </nav>
        <!-- Bootstrap core JS-->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Core theme JS-->
        <script src="../js/scripts.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: We don't have a [mre] I don't think? Is there any HTML in the `header.php`? What about in `footer.php`?

Comment: It really makes no sense that the sidebar is a complete, separate HTML document. I suspect that might be part of the problem. It should only be the code needed for the side bar, not a totally separate HTML page with its own header, CSS etc. The `</html` tag should not appear until right at the end of the complete page (which presumably should be in the footer, really) and there should be only one in the complete page. Same for the opening html tag, and head and body tags. Anod no HTML should be outside those tags, unlike what you have now

Comment: From those class names it looks like you're using Bootstrap for the design. If that's the case, set the body tag as: <body class="container-fluid">

Comment: FYI -- this has nothing to do with PHP, so the php tag is erroneous.

Comment: im a pretty new to coding so it might look a little weird

Comment: @StarMANJ I added an actual answer, so it can be found by others. Please mark as the resolved answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From those class names it looks like you're using Bootstrap for the design. If that's the case, set the body tag as:

```
<body class="container-fluid">
```